# Where is the key to the Cambridge Police Station?

Tags: fallout-4

I just defeated the Ghouls in the "Fire Support" mission in Fallout 4. The next step is to talk to Paladin Danse who appears to be on the top of the station. However, the entrance to the station is locked and says it can only be opened with a key. Where is the key to the police station?

Comment: Paladin Danse isn't supposed to be on the roof, he's supposed to be in the court yard... after speaking to him you'll be invited inside...

Comment: There's another entrance in the garage to the left of the station's front entrance. I don't recall if it requires a key or if it can be lockpicked but you can try do enter the station from there.

Comment: @Ben I think the garage only opens from the inside as well

Comment: @Ben, the garage door appears to be closed. Danse is definitely on the roof in the power armor. There is also an injured Knight Rhys being patched up by a Scribe Haylen in the courtyard, but neither of them are helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paladin Danse has the key to the Cambridge Police Station. Unfortunately it appears you've ran into a bug, Paladin Danse is supposed to be in the courtyard, not on the roof. If you're playing on a console version of the game you will need to reload the game and hope that the next time you arrive at the Cambridge Police Station to provide Fire Support that he has spawned in the correct place.

If you're playing on PC you can use the cheat for noclipping and float up to the roof to speak to him. This should "fix" the issue (since he turns around and walks into the police station).

Comment: I've successfully gotten on the roof thanks to this [reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3scp3g/cambridge_police_station_bug/cxgfmvv).
Using a set of power armor as an extra step to jump from the ledge onto the garage.

Comment: Unfortunately, after talking to him on the roof and having haylen tell me about the transmitter, he is now shown as "This individual is busy" and the quest in my pipboy still says I need to talk to Danse. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use the console command to open the front door. Then walk to the roof to talk to him. After this, it is possible that the popup "is busy" will appear.

There is another door on the roof. Open it via console command.

Then try to talk to him again to advance.

Comment: You could do a lot of stuff from the console... but I wouldn't call using that a solution to this.

Comment: I'm on the PS4, so I don't exactly have a console I can use :)